# Possible to write R code inside Openrefine?

Tags: r, openrefine

I am using Openrefine in extensive projects and one of the options that are very useful is the ability to use programming languages to help in the data cleaning processes. In this way, any one knows if R can be add in OpenRefine? Python, Closure and GREL are already in there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. No, you can't, but feel free to ask this enhancement [on Github](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1226). This kind of question is not well suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm wondering, from the Jython language, can't we load R code ?

Comment: @iMitwe Maybe using some Python module. [rp2](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/overview.html#installation) is written in C, so it cannot be installed on Jython.

Comment: I haven´t tried this possibility of Jython witn R inside, but from my tests with R inside Python it lacks of several functionalities related non standard packages and so on.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not currently possible.  I plan to meetup with the Dallas R Lang users group shortly to discuss HOW they envision using R with OpenRefine.  For now, you are welcome to add a link to a document or blog that describes your ideas as to what your expectations would be regarding using R in OpenRefine.  Add that link to our existing issue here: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1226